# Union tables with LINQ query for custom Model

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have 3 tables(in origin its 6 but shorter better here) 
they all have have a key column in common I want to filter and union all these tables using linq

Here what I did so far, actually it works but you will understand me why I post this since you saw the code below

```
        var query = (from icr in ictetkikRadyoloji
                                 where icr.CommanId == userId                                 
                                select new MyCustomModel
                                 {

                                     ID = icr.ID,
                                     IstemTarihi = icr.IstemTarihi,
                                     Laboratuvar = icr.Laboratuvar,
                                     Sonuc = icr.Sonuc,
                                     HastaGuid = "-",
                                     Type_ = "1"
                                 }).Union(from icb in ictetkikBakteriyoloji
                                          where icb.CommanId == userId                                      select new MyCustomModel
                                          {

                                              ID = icb.ID,
                                              IstemTarihi = icb.IstemTarihi,
                                              Laboratuvar = icb.Laboratuvar,
                                              Sonuc = "-",
                                              HastaGuid ="someGuid",
                                              Type_ = "2"
                                          }).Union(from icbk in ictetkikBiyokimya
                                                   where icbk.CommanId == userId                                               select new MyCustomModel
                                                   {

                                                       ID = icbk.ID,
                                                       IstemTarihi = DateTime.Now,
                                                       Laboratuvar = icbk.Laboratuvar,
                                                       Sonuc = "-",
                                                       HastaGuid ="SomeGuid",
                                                       Type_ = "3"
                                                   });
```

You see its so ugly and its uglier than this in origin :( how can I make this little bit more beauty, since they all return entities as specific Model(MyCustomModel)
I feel like it can be..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first perform projection and then union over all cases. The only additional data that projection should have is `CommanId`. You can use [anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types), so you don't have to create another class just for intermediate projection. After that you can specify your filter just once and do final projection to `MyCustomModel`.

For example:

```
var unionQuery = (from icr in ictetkikRadyoloji
                    select new 
                    {
                        ID = icr.ID,
                        IstemTarihi = icr.IstemTarihi,
                        Laboratuvar = icr.Laboratuvar,
                        Sonuc = icr.Sonuc,
                        HastaGuid = "-",
                        Type_ = "1",
                        CommanId = icr.CommanId
                    }).Union(
                    (from icb in ictetkikBakteriyoloji
                    select new
                    {

                        ID = icb.ID,
                        IstemTarihi = icb.IstemTarihi,
                        Laboratuvar = icb.Laboratuvar,
                        Sonuc = "-",
                        HastaGuid = "someGuid",
                        Type_ = "2",
                        CommanId = icb.CommanId
                    })).Union(
                    (from icbk in ictetkikBiyokimya
                    select new
                    {

                        ID = icbk.ID,
                        IstemTarihi = DateTime.Now,
                        Laboratuvar = icbk.Laboratuvar,
                        Sonuc = "-",
                        HastaGuid = "SomeGuid",
                        Type_ = "3",
                        CommanId = icbk.CommanId
                    }));

var query = from i in unionQuery
            where i.CommanId = userId
            select new MyCustomModel
            {
                ID = i.ID,
                IstemTarihi = i.IstemTarihi,
                Laboratuvar = i.Laboratuvar,
                Sonuc = "-",
                HastaGuid = "SomeGuid",
                Type_ = "3",
            };
```

Alternatively you could add property `CommanId` to `MyCustomModel` and then you don't need final projection and anonymous types.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

**1. Get List of Lists**

```
            var query = (from icr in ictetkikRadyoloji
            where icr.CommanId == userId
            select new List<MyCustomModel>()
            {
                new MyCustomModel()
                {

                    ID = icr.ID,
                    IstemTarihi = icr.IstemTarihi,
                    Laboratuvar = icr.Laboratuvar,
                    Sonuc = icr.Sonuc,
                    HastaGuid = "-",
                    Type_ = "1"
                },
               new MyCustomModel
               {

                   ID = icb.ID,
                   IstemTarihi = icb.IstemTarihi,
                   Laboratuvar = icb.Laboratuvar,
                   Sonuc = "-",
                   HastaGuid = "someGuid",
                   Type_ = "2"
               },
               new MyCustomModel
               {

                   ID = icbk.ID,
                   IstemTarihi = DateTime.Now,
                   Laboratuvar = icbk.Laboratuvar,
                   Sonuc = "-",
                   HastaGuid = "SomeGuid",
                   Type_ = "3"
               }
            });
```

**2. Use loop through Objects**

Load objects to memory and make 3 different copies of each object.

```
        var result = new List<MyCustomModel>();
        var query = (from icr in ictetkikRadyoloji
                where icr.CommanId == userId
                select icr)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(x =>
            {
                result.Add(new MyCustomModel()
                {

                    ID = icr.ID,
                    IstemTarihi = icr.IstemTarihi,
                    Laboratuvar = icr.Laboratuvar,
                    Sonuc = icr.Sonuc,
                    HastaGuid = "-",
                    Type_ = "1"
                });

                result.Add(new MyCustomModel()
                {

                    ID = icr.ID,
                    IstemTarihi = icr.IstemTarihi,
                    Laboratuvar = icr.Laboratuvar,
                    Sonuc = "-",
                    HastaGuid = "someGuid",
                    Type_ = "2"
                });

                result.Add(new MyCustomModel()
                {

                    ID = icr.ID,
                    IstemTarihi = DateTime.Now,
                    Laboratuvar = icr.Laboratuvar,
                    Sonuc = "-",
                    HastaGuid = "SomeGuid",
                    Type_ = "3"
                });

            });
```